# CSS border image doesn't show the full image

Tags: css, border-image

I want to have [this image](http://i68.tinypic.com/ofdizn.png) repeated on the buttom border. It works fine, except for the fact that it won't show me the full width image but only the middle part of it. What do I need to do so it repeats the full image?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnp67et0/2/)

My code:

```css
#test {
  background-color: #7ab828;
  border: 17px solid transparent;
  -webkit-border-image: url(http://i68.tinypic.com/ofdizn.png) 17 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
  -o-border-image: url(http://i68.tinypic.com/ofdizn.png) 17 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
  border-image: url(http://i68.tinypic.com/ofdizn.png) 17 round;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

edit:

I found out how to do it (at least in my case that worked how I wanted it to). I figured that since `border-image-slice` slices the image into 9 parts and only repeats the middle, I edited my image so it showed the same part 3 times. Now the image is sliced and the middle part is still the full image.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this CSS property:

> [***border-image-width***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-width)
>
> The `border-image-width` CSS property defines the width of the border
>   image by defining inward offsets from the border edges. If the
>   `border-image-width` is greater than the `border-width`, then the
>   border image extends beyond the padding (and/or content) edge.